# appending to YAML file using go lang

Tags: go, yaml, glide-golang, go-structtag

I writing a golang program which append rule to the file as mentioned below
Required format:

```
customRules:
  custom-rules.yaml: |-
    - rule: Pod Created in Kube Namespace
      append: true
      condition: and (k8s_audit_never_true)
      source: k8s_audit
    - rule: Create files below dev
      append: true
      condition: and (never_true)
      source: syscall
```

I wrote a go program which failing to be in the above format I can't get what Iam missing.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type AutoGenerated struct {
    CustomRules CustomRules `yaml:"customRules"`
}
type CustomRulesYaml struct {
    Rule      string `yaml:"rule"`
    Append    bool   `yaml:"append"`
    Condition string `yaml:"condition"`
    Source    string `yaml:"source"`
}
type CustomRules struct {
    CustomRulesYaml []CustomRulesYaml `yaml:"custom-rules.yaml"`
}

func main() {
    // yfile, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/home/revaa/falco/custom_rules.yaml")
    // if err != nil {
    //  log.Fatal(err)
    // }
    c1 := CustomRulesYaml{"K8s serviceaccount created", false, "(never_true)", "k8s-audit"}
    c2 := CustomRulesYaml{"k8s service created", false, "never_true", "k8s-audit"}
    c := []CustomRulesYaml{c1, c2}
    c3 := CustomRules{c}
    data := AutoGenerated{c3}
    check, err := yaml.Marshal(&data)

    if err != nil {

        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err2 := ioutil.WriteFile("/home/revaa/falco/custom_rules.yaml", check, 0)

    if err2 != nil {

        log.Fatal(err2)
    }

    fmt.Println("data written")

}
```

Here is my go code, on running the program the YAML is not getting appended in the above format. The values are appended as below instead.

```
customRules:
  custom-rules.yaml:
  - rule: K8s serviceaccount created
    append: false
    condition: (never_true)
    source: k8s-audit
  - rule: k8s service created
    append: false
    condition: never_true
    source: k8s-audit
```

Why Iam not getting the YAML file in the required format?

Answer (score 1):

Your required input format represents the following YAML structure:

- There is a dictionary with one key-value pair.

  - The key is `customRules`.
  - The value is a dictionary.

The dictionary stored in the value above has one entry:

- The key is `custom-rules.yaml`.
- The value is a string.

The string stored in the value above is:

```
"- rule: Pod Created in Kube Namespace\n  append: true\n  condition: and (k8s_audit_never_true)\n  source: k8s_audit\n- rule: Create files below dev\n  append: true\n  condition: and (never_true)\n  source: syscall"
```

That is, this *is not a list type*.  It's a single string.

Now, the fact is that this single string *is* valid—albeit slightly dodgy—YAML, and if read, it will *produce* a list (a slice, in Go) of 2 elements, each of which is a dictionary (generally corresponding to a map or struct type in Go).

Your code is close to right, then, if you really do need this.  Instead of wrapping the `[]CustomRulesYaml` in a type, you need to marshal *twice*.  [Here's a variant of your code on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/X-8GIj1N0si) whose output is:

```yaml
custom-rules.yaml: |
  - rule: K8s serviceaccount created
    append: false
    condition: (never_true)
    source: k8s-audit
  - rule: k8s service created
    append: false
    condition: never_true
    source: k8s-audit
```

Now, note that this output has a pipe symbol `|` without a suffix hyphen `-`.  That's because the marshaled string, `string(asBytes)`, *ends with a newline*.  It probably *should* end with a newline, which is why `yaml.Marshal` produced one.  But your sample input *doesn't* end with a newline, which is why your sample input has `|-` instead of just `|`: the `-` means "don't include that newline".

To get *that* from your existing code, you will have to strip off the newline, e.g., add:

```
asBytes = asBytes[0:len(asBytes)-1] // delete trailing newline
```

before building the string in `c3` and marshaling it.

Comment: Tysm how to make it display under the CustomRules as in the required format